# Referencing .dll to dotnet core 2.2

Tags: dll, .net-core, reference, interop

I have added a `.dll` reference file to my project. However, when I rebuild it says

> the assembly path ' ' is invalid. Assembly paths must be rooted.

I don't get what the error really means.

Is there any way or a tool to check if a `.dll` is compatible with my application?

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution from here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21480

Add the following text in the .csproj file. Works perfectly, even in .NET Core 3.1:

```
<Target Name="resolveInteropOutputPath" BeforeTargets="ResolveComReferences"
      Condition="'@(COMReference)'!='' or '@(COMFileReference)'!=''">
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(InteropOutputPath)' == '' ">
  <InteropOutputPath>$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\$(IntermediateOutputPath)</InteropOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are referencing a COM library mentioned in the [github isse](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5086)

i am quoting the answer from [strangegt](https://github.com/strangegt):

> I find a workaround for solve this. Copy the Interop....dll to project
>   root, and mark it for copy on compile Remove the old reference, and
>   reference the file in root folder.
>   Then all compile, and works, almost for my using some system COM library

Comment: I've read about that. I just didn't get the part `Copy the Interop....dll to project root, and mark it for copy on compile`

Comment: Physically copy the original file that you like to reference also into the Root of your Application. E.g. Where *.csproj is

Comment: Then you Need to post a more detailed example so that we can reproduce your scenario. Maybach you can post a github repo.

Comment: I'm trying to, it's just that.. it is as simple as that. I added a `.dll`, it won't compile saying which error.

Comment: Perhaps this might help, the `.dll` is `Interop.MD5Enc.dll`.

Comment: as i said: please provide a github repo with your problem. Otherwise it is difficult to get the point. When i search for "Interop.MD5Enc.dll" i do not find anything

Comment: This method did not work for me, while @Himanshu Patel 's below did (I am using .NET Core 3.1).